# Indentation with Let Statements

Tags: haskell

I'm afraid I'm tapped out on understanding this and the `let` block in general.

The following code:

```
splitWith tf xs 
    |(null xs) = [[]]
    |((length xs) == 1) = [xs]
    |otherwise = let tpl = (break tf xs) 
                     x = (fst tpl) 
                     xrst =  (snd tpl)
         in [[x] ,(splitWith tf (tail xrst))]
```

Creates this syntax error:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ch04_exercise.hs, interpreted )
>   ch04_exercise.hs:31:26: parse error on input ‘x’

This happened after I got rid of tabs in Sublime Text 2 and put spaces in to line up the variables.  Before I did that I got the syntax error at the = sign after the `x`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be that I need to put the actual assignments on the following line. Is that correct?

Comment: Found [this description](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) of Haskell indentation.

Comment: I'm thinking that my example was somehow messing up with tab stops so that the number of spaces before the `tpl` let was not really at the same point as the following lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in` has to line up with the `let` or be on the same line:

```
| otherwise = let (x, xrst) = break tf xs
              in [[x], splitWith tf (tail xrst)]
```

Which is why I usually prefer putting `let` on its own line:

```
| otherwise =
    let (x, xrst) = break tf xs
    in [[x], splitWith tf (tail xrst)]
```

You also have unnecessary parentheses and could benefit from some pattern matching (as demonstrated above).

Comment: No, in this example the `in` can be anywhere on the subsequent line other than the left column. This is the perennial tabs issue - the bindings don't line up.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is complaining about the `x = (fst tpl)` because its left edge doesn't line up with `tpl =`.

You got rid of only some of the tabs. I'll put tab as `<------>` and space as `.`:

```
splitWith tf xs 
<------><------>|(null xs) = [[]]
<------><------>|((length xs) == 1) = [xs]
<------><------>|otherwise = let tpl = (break tf xs) 
.........................x = (fst tpl) 
.........................xrst =  (snd tpl)
<------><------>.....in [[x] ,(splitWith tf (tail xrst))]
```

The compiler uses tabstops at multiples of 8. The difference of 8 between where you thought `tpl =` was and where the compiler thinks it is suggests your editor has tabstops at multiples of 4, which would look like:

```
splitWith tf xs 
<--><-->|(null xs) = [[]]
<--><-->|((length xs) == 1) = [xs]
<--><-->|otherwise = let tpl = (break tf xs) 
.........................x = (fst tpl) 
.........................xrst =  (snd tpl)
<--><-->.....in [[x] ,(splitWith tf (tail xrst))]
```

This looks nice and correct, but it's not how the compiler sees it!

### It's easiest if you stick to spaces. Change your editor's settings.

If you use just spaces without any tabs at all, you can't get this problem, because your editor has to show it the way the compiler thinks about it.

My editor lets me specify that when I press tab, it should insert the number of spaces that a tab would show as, so I use that, which is safe for a tabstop of 4. If your editor can do that, use that option. (If not, consider getting a cleverer editor for when you're programming.)

My editor also has auto indent and outdent, where the next line copies the whitespace indentation of the previous line - this avoids the problem. Turn this on if your editor supports it, because it saves you effort and you're less likely to get the parse error. (When I then press backspace, my editor deletes back to the previous level of indentation, which is nice.)

Almost all editors can change how they display tabs. If you can't get it to use spaces for tabs, you should change the tabstop to be 8, because that matches ghc, and you're much less likely to get this error, but you're still better off using spaces.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I did that earlier today in Sublime 2 and my life has gotten much nicer since then.  Great job presenting the information!

Comment: @RaySalemi I agree with bheklilr that you have a lot of unnecessary brackets - the only ones you need are on the last line `tail xrst`. You also probably mean `x:splitWith tf (tail xrst)`. There's another problem once the code compiles - try out `splitWith (==0) [1,2,3,0,4,5,6]` and `splitWith (==0) [1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0,0,0,0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiled (though the types are wrong)

I think the general lesson learned here is that it's easier to line up the `let` assignments if you start them on the next line.

```
splitWith tf xs 
    |(null xs) = [[]]
    |((length xs) == 1) = [xs]
    |otherwise = let 
                    tpl = (break tf xs) 
                    x = (fst tpl) 
                    xrst =  (snd tpl)
                 in [[x] ,(splitWith tf (tail xrst))]
```