# Haskell: Do block, last statement must be expression

Tags: haskell, expression

I want to know the difference when I right or left click on a button. I wrote the following code:

```hs
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Control.Monad.IO.Class 

--main::IO()
main = do
    initGUI

window <- windowNew

    button <- buttonNewWithLabel "button"

    on button buttonPressEvent (tryEvent (do button <- eventButton

                                             liftIO (extrafunctie button)
                                             ))                                         
    containerAdd window button

    onDestroy window mainQuit

    widgetShowAll window

    mainGUI

extrafunctie b = if (RightButton == b) 
                 then putStrLn "True"
                 else putStrLn "False"
```

I get the following error:

```
jolien@jolien-VirtualBox:~/Documenten/haskell$ ghc --make test.hs -o test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:9:50:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      button <- eventButton liftIO (extrafunctie button)
```

I've looked at my indentation, which is correct. Does someone know a solution?

Comment: This does look like an indentation problem. Have you checked for tab characters? IIRC Haskell interprets them as "tab to next multiple of 8 spaces", maybe your editor does differently.

Comment: `button <- eventButton;` :D

Comment: Checked with `ghc` and the code you pasted here seems OK as far as indentation is concerned, so there's probably some invisible character and/or tabs like @Tarmil suggested.  I suspect the code was not pasted into the question properly.

Comment: Apologies, folks. I had removed all tabs in my previous edit. I've restored the OP's code to its original form.

Comment: FYI The StackOverflow engine converts tabs into four spaces when it renders the MarkDown source as HTML, however when you click "edit" and look at the original source, there are tabs there.

Comment: @d12frosted Your solution is indeed the correct one. Could you give an explanation why to use the ";" because i don't think you need to type the ";" after every line

Comment: @JoJoD It works because indentation is a sort of implicit `{`, `;` & `}` and you can give them explicitly if you want. The problem is indentation, and you can see it if you set your editor's tab stops to 8, or replace all your tabs with spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27714157/1598537

Comment: Why did you comment the `main` function type out? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the compiler sees your code, with tabstops at 8 character intervals.
I'll show a tab as `-------|` and spaces as `.`:

```
>....import Graphics.UI.Gtk
>....import Control.Monad.IO.Class 
>
>....--main::IO()
>....main = do
>....-|initGUI

>...--|window <- windowNew

>....-|button <- buttonNewWithLabel "button"

>....-|on button buttonPressEvent (tryEvent (do button <- eventButton

>....-|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|..----|.liftIO (extrafunctie button)
>....-|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|.....))                                           
>....-|containerAdd window button

>....-|onDestroy window mainQuit

>....-|widgetShowAll window

>....-|mainGUI
>
>....extrafunctie b = if (RightButton == b) 
>....-|------|------|------|.then putStrLn "True"
>....-|------|------|------|.else putStrLn "False"
```

As you can see, the compiler sees the `liftIO (extrafunctie` bit as much further to the right.
If you use spaces to lay out your work this can't happen:

```
>    import Graphics.UI.Gtk
>    import Control.Monad.IO.Class 
>
>    --main::IO()
>    main = do
>      initGUI
>      window <- windowNew
>      button <- buttonNewWithLabel "button"
>      on button buttonPressEvent (tryEvent (do button <- eventButton
>                                               liftIO (extrafunctie button)
>                                               ))                                             
>      containerAdd window button
>      onDestroy window mainQuit
>      widgetShowAll window
>      mainGUI
>
>    extrafunctie b = if (RightButton == b) 
>                  then putStrLn "True"
>                  else putStrLn "False"
```

### It's easiest if you stick to spaces. Change your editor's settings.

If you use just spaces without any tabs at all, you can't get this problem, because your editor has to show it the way the compiler thinks about it.

My editor lets me specify that when I press tab, it should insert the number of spaces that a tab would show as, so I use that, which is safe for a tabstop of 4. If your editor can do that, use that option. (If not, consider getting a cleverer editor for when you're programming.)

My editor also has auto indent and outdent, where the next line copies the whitespace indentation of the previous line - this avoids the problem. Turn this on if your editor supports it, because it saves you effort and you're less likely to get the parse error. (When I then press backspace, my editor deletes back to the previous level of indentation, which is nice.)

Almost all editors can change how they display tabs. If you can't get it to use spaces for tabs, you should change the tabstop to be 8, because that matches ghc, and you're much less likely to get this error, but you're still better off using spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is terrible, that's the problem. You need to replace this:

```
on button buttonPressEvent (tryEvent (do button <- eventButton

                                         liftIO (extrafunctie button)
                                         ))
```

with:

```
on button buttonPressEvent $
    tryEvent $ do 
        button <- eventButton
        liftIO (extrafunctie button)
```

Also you can replace your `extrafunctie` function with:

```
extrafunctie b = print (RightButton == b)
```

Answer (score -1):

How's the following?

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Control.Monad.IO.Class 

--main::IO()
main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  button <- buttonNewWithLabel "button"
  on button buttonPressEvent (tryEvent (do button <- eventButton
                                         liftIO (extrafunctie button)
                                         ))                                      
  containerAdd window button
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI

extrafunctie b = if (RightButton == b) 
           then putStrLn "True"
           else putStrLn "False"
```

Comment: Not good because the extrafunctie is in the main function ==> can't do  that (parse error on =)

Comment: Thought my indentation would make a difference. Looking forward to the answer.